# Angular 2 Parent View Not Updating after Observable change

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have an Observable service which I'm using to coordinate data between components. In this instance, I'm trying to use it to control which components / html should be visible at one time.

When I set the value to true of the behavior subject which the parent component subscribes to, it shows the child component (transform-addedit) successfully. However, when I update the service member which controls this (mapAddingTransformSubj) from the child component, the view isn't switching back even though I subscribed in the parent. I did confirm that the parent is receiving the value of the observable properly.

If anyone can suggest a better way to do this, I'd be grateful!

The parent component html:

```
<div class="container-fluid custom-container">
    <div *ngIf="!addingTransform">
        //Some html
         <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="addNewTransform()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Transformation</button>
    </div>
   <div *ngIf="addingTransform">
       <transform-addedit></transform-addedit>
   </div>
</div>
```

Parent component .ts:

```
    //Toggles whether or not to show the Transformation components
    public addingTransform: boolean;
    active: boolean = true;

    //Subscriptions for map create service
    addingTransformSubscription: Subscription;

    //Sets the visible component to the transform add/edit component
    addNewTransform() {
        this.mapAddEditService.setAddingTransform(true);    
    }

    constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private mapAddEditService: MapAddEditService) {
        this.addingTransformSubscription = this.mapAddEditService.getAddingTransform().subscribe(addingTransform => this.addingTransform = addingTransform);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
    }
}
```

Child component .ts:

```
    cancelTransform() {
        this.mapAddEditService.setAddingTransform(false);
    }

    constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private mapAddEditService: MapAddEditService) {
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
```

Part of my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MapAddEditService {
    private mapAddingTransformSubj = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    setAddingTransform(addingTransform: boolean) {
        this.mapAddingTransformSubj.next(addingTransform);
    }
    getAddingTransform() {
        return this.mapAddingTransformSubj.asObservable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this, and it was kinda a silly problem

I realized that ngIf does checking on init, so binding to the [hidden] within each of the parent component html divs instead of ngIf property fixed my issue.